# How can you sync your iPod with Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ipod, windows-media-player

How can I add music to my iPod using Windows Media Player on Windows 7? I assume you need a plugin of some sorts (if not, please correct me!). Do you have any to recommend?

I have found one called [MGTEK dopisp](http://www.mgtek.com/dopisp/) which seems promising from their website at least, but it is not free. I might buy it if it is good, but just thought I would ask here if anyone know of any other alternatives that are cheaper or better, or both =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This works perfectly!](http://www.mgtek.com/dopisp/)

Comment: Have you used it a lot? I have just installed it and added some music to my iPod once. But it seems pretty smooth!

Comment: I think I have used it once. Glad to hear it is working.

Comment: If *think* you have used it once. How can you say it works perfectly? :p

Comment: Well it worked 1 out 1 didn't it? LOL That's 100% success rate! :P

Comment: I guess I will have to give you that one :p